# preg_match - can only consist of numbers, hyphens(-) and spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Does anybody know using regular expression with preg_match how can I allow in a string only numbers, hyphens(-) and spaces?

Is that expression good enough?

```
preg_match('/[^a-z\s-]/i', $_POST['phone'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not good enough because you assume that there is only latin letters, white characters and hyphen in the world!

The simpliest way is to write what you need *(instead of what you don't need)*:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9- ]+$/D', $_POST['phone']);
```

or

```
preg_match('/^[0-9-\s]+$/D', $_POST['phone']); // for any kind of white spaces
```

Note the quantifier `+` to repeat the character class and the anchors (`^` for start and `$` for end) to ensure that the string is checked from start until the end. The `D` modifier avoids to have a newline at the end *(it gives the `$` anchor a strict meaning, otherwise `$` can match the end of the string just before a last newline (a strange behaviour isn't it?))*.

Comment: Please escape that hyphen in the middle of your character class (or place it at the start or end).

Comment: @ridgerunner: you don't need to escape the hyphen after a range or a character class shortcut in a character class.

Comment: First thanks this helped me a lot. I have a question since the pattern accepting multiple dashes ---- how can we strict it to accept only one dash in the middle of words not in the beginning not in the end. I want it to accept this one i-am-a-good-boy but not this one ----i-am---not---a---good---boy---

Comment: How to add here also a check for words DUP and POP ?